# Can someone help me with "unknown type name 'treeElement'" error?

Tags: c

```
typedef void* treeElementData;

// A linked list node - instrument for define the sons of treeElement
typedef struct sons_list {
    treeElementData data;
    struct tree_element *next;
} sonsList;

typedef struct tree_element {
    treeElementData data;
    sonsList* sons_element;
    treeElement* parent;                // Here is the place of the error.
} treeElement;

typedef struct tree_root {
    treeElement* root;
} treeRoot;
```

Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

```
unknown type name 'treeElement' error
```

Comment: Sure I can help. Look at the line the error is mentioning. Then look at all lines before. Where in those earlier lines is the declaration of the type `treeElement` ? You could show us the exact error message and identify the mentioned line by the way.

Comment: `treeElement* parent;` => `struct tree_element * parent;`. Plus don't typedef pointer type thank for humanity.

Comment: This is a very common problem, so there ought to be a duplicate question for it.  I've not been able to find one yet.  Part of the trouble is that it's also an elementary problem, so questions tend to get down-voted and/or closed rather quickly because once you know the solution, they aren't very interesting.  If anyone has a good question to duplicate this to, please let me know (an `@Jonathan` comment here is fine, or see my profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are declaring your struct, your typedef is not already effective (the typedef  is usable at the end of the structure declaration (ie : after `} treeElement;`)

You need to use the complet notation to reference your structure so `struct tree_element* parent`

If you absolutly want to use your define inside your structure declaration, you can set your typedef before like that :

```
typedef struct tree_element treeElement;
struct tree_element {
    treeElementData data;
    sonsList* sons_element;
    treeElement* parent;
};
```

But it's seems a bit weird to typedef a struct that's not yet declare at my opinion.